# Airflow sensor task only wait for a certain period

Tags: python, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a workflow so that a sensor task wait for external dag to complete, for only wait for a certain number of days. It's a daily job so I'd like a sensor job to wait for example 3 days, and on the forth day send out an email, and either waiting or do some other task.

Could someone please help to shed some light on how to achieve this? Also how do we communicate the "days counter" from one day to another? Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `ExternalTaskSensor` with the following configurations:

- `timeout = 3 * 24 * 60 * 60` - 3 days in seconds, after that time sensor will fail
- `poke_interval = 12 * 60 * 60` - 12h between sensor checks, you can adjust  it to let say a check every hour. It will reduce number of times when you check the external dag state
- `mode = "reschedule"` - in this way the sensor will not occupy worker slot for 3 days, it will be scheduled, executed and if condition is not met it will be rescheduled to be executed in next `poke_interval` seconds. It's a good practice to use this mode for long running tasks.

Additionally you can build your waiting DAG as `wait_task >> [success_task , fail_task]` where

- `wait_task` is your sensor
- `success_task` has trigger rule `all_success` and is followed when   the sensors succeeds
- `fail_task` with `all_failed` trigger rule and handles scenario when sensor finally return false or timeouts

Comment: Adding to the requirement of sensing for x days, ExternalTaskSensor has `execution_date_fn` which can be used to sense for certain execution of remote dag. For example, Attach a function to this argument which returns list of three execution dates pf remote dag.

Comment: @Tomasz Urbaszek Thanks but the thing is one senario would be I want the sensor to only send an email and keep waiting (like email to notify SLA has passed). How/where can I add in this function?

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to achieve is have an option to not `time out`

Comment: @user4046073 in that case set timeout to for example 2 weeks or `float('inf')`. But in that case remember to use `reschedule` mode.

Comment: @Tomasz Urbaszek thanks. Having timeout will have the sensor fail after 2 weeks? I was hoping to have an option to Not fail/ not `time out`. So if I don't have `timeout`, it will just keep waiting? If it don't use `time out`, have it on `reschedule` mode is still a good idea?

Comment: In general having "always running tasks" is not the best pattern in my opinion. But yes, you can set timeout probably to `float('inf')` so it never timeouts, if you don't set it the default value of 7 days will be used. Using `reschedule` mode is always recommended for something that runs longer than a minute.